# use riak pre-commit hook to validate json schema

Tags: riak, jsonschema

I would like to use a pre-commit hook in riak to validate the json schema of the data submitted

There are a number of implementations in javascript on json-schema.org

http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

is there a way to load an external library or libraries into riak so i can use them inside the pre- and post-commit hooks

and preferably also the external schema definition files (or at least load them from a bucket)

I use clients in multiple languages to submit data to riak, and it would be ideal if riak could do the validtion of all data submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got my awnser from the mailing list,

> Yes. For JavaScript, this can be done in app.config in 'js_source_dir'
>   in the 'riak_kv' settings:
>
> `{js_source_dir, "/etc/riak/javascript"},`